# Django - matching query does not exists

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I've create a view and in that view I declared variable for Address Model.  Now when I am calling forms built on these models it is showing me the error. I used ForeignKey for user and in form User field was popping up multiple times. So I also need a simplest solution to merge a single form with multiple models with ForeignKeys. Here is my View.

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    address = Address.objects.get(user=user)

    picture = UserPicture.objects.get(user=user)
    job = Job.Objects.get(user=user)
    address_form = AddressForm(request.POST or None, instance=address)
    job_form = JobForm(request.POST or None, instance=job)

    user_picture_form = UserPictureForm(request.POST or None, instance=picture)
    return render_to_response('profiles/edit_profiles.html', locals(),\n
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Form is something like:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Job, Address, UserPicture
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
class UserPictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPicture
```

Template has following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
    {{ address_form.as_p }}
</div>
     <div class="row">
     {{ job_form.as_p }}
     </div>
    <div class="row">
    {{ user_picture_form.as_p }}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

My models are:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city


 class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    employer_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.position

 class UserPicture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Error is Below:

```
DoesNotExist at /edit/
Address matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/edit/
Django Version: 1.6.8
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Address matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Mudassar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 310
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Mudassar\\PycharmProjects\\matcher',
 'C:\\windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Users\\Mudassar\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
Server time:    Wed, 12 Aug 2015 23:50:55 +0500
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Users\Mudassar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Mudassar\PycharmProjects\matcher\profiles\views.py in edit_profile
address = Address.objects.get(user=user) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Advise requested.

Comment: Post your models please. Seems like a quick fix but I have to see what your foreign key relationships look like.

Comment: Posted my models above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a few conditionals it appears. You need to create these objects before you can get them so first create them like so. Then once the objects are created you can do what you where trying to do, get_or_create would not work well here because you want to give your user a form to enter their profile information, even though you could set defaults but this is much simpler to understand.

```
import django.shortcuts import render
def add_profile(request):
   context = {}
   if request.method == 'POST':
      address_form = AddressForm(request.POST)
      job_form = JobForm(request.POST)
      user_picture_form = UserPictureForm(request.POST)
      if address_form.is_valid() and job_form.is_valid() and user_picture_form.is_valid():
        adress_form.save()
        job_form.save()
        user_picture_form.save()
      else:
         print adress_form.errors, job_form.errors, user_picture_form.errors
    else:
      context['address_form'] = AddressForm()
      context['job_form'] = JobForm()
      context['user_picture_form'] = UserPictureForm()         
     return render(request, 'profiles/add_profiles.html', context)



def edit_profile(request):
   context = {}
   user = request.user
   adress = Adress.objects.get(user=user)
   job = Job.objects.get(user=user)
   picture = UserPicture.objects.get(user=user)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      address_form = AddressForm(request.POST, instance=adress)
      job_form = JobForm(request.POST, instance=job)
      user_picture_form = UserPictureForm(request.POST, instance=picture)
      if address_form.is_valid() and job_form.is_valid() and user_picture_form.is_valid():
        adress_form.save()
        job_form.save()
        user_picture_form.save()
      else:
         print adress_form.errors, job_form.errors, user_picture_form.errors
    else:
      context['address_form'] = AddressForm(instance=adress)
      context['job_form'] = JobForm(instance=job)
      context['user_picture_form'] = UserPictureForm(instance=picture)         
     return render(request, 'profiles/edit_profiles.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks @appa_lover you really helped me to understand the concept. Thanks for saving the day for me.

Comment: Now the form information entered by user is not showing up. But will fix it. But if you have a quick way around let me know.

Comment: Okay I renamed both of the methods one to add_profile the other to edit_profile, once you have a user profile for the user, you would be able to use edit_profile. Make two different HTML files for each and two different URLS for each. The I would write a conditional so if the requested user has a user profile show only the edit_profile link, if the user still needs a profile show the add profile link, if you want me to add that I will in an hour or so.

Comment: Thanks and I also solved the problem I posted at the first place with modelformset_factory. But your solution helped me to lead there. Thanks. God Bless

Answer (score 1):

```
address = Address.objects.get(user=user)
```

It looks like there isn't an address yet for this user, so you need to create it before this. There is a handy shortcut [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) that does this for you.

Comment: Tried that...then it shows "IntegrityError at /edit/ profiles_address.zip_code may not be NULL". If I set null=True...same error. If I set it to False same error again.

Comment: Then why are you creating the adress object before you have that data? Model forms are there to save form-data into models ... Like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view only with `form.save()` for the `is_valid()` block

Comment: I did filled up form from admin and Address is saved successfully. What I need to achieve is that the combined form should show "User ID" field once. Secondly I need to make users able to see the data and last data should be there that saved earlier. So they can make changes in data already showing up in forms as per need.

Comment: `try: address=Adress...; except Address.DoesNotExist: address=None; form=addr_form(instance=address, initial={'user'=request.user});` Instance ensures the already entered data gets displayed.

Comment: Nope not working. Resulted same error and this is getting really strange now. Thanks anyway.